# Pull Scenarios & Steps from server (Zephyr for JIRA)

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I would like a single *"source of truth"* for my specifications and test results. Currently we use JIRA to track issues and in particular we use the Zephyr plugin to maintain information about test cycles.

The goal is to write the features as part of the Zephyr test definition and have Cucumber pull them down and run them instead of looking for `scenario.feature` files. The Zephyr ReST API will allow us to get the information I'm pretty sure, how can I plug that text into the Cucumber run?

I have had a look at the [Cucumber source code](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) and I can see that I could possibly extend the `ResourceLoader`, `ResourceIterable`, `Resource` etc... to get it to pull from a ReST Service. 
Has anyone else done this, or know of a free plugin? Or is there a non-coding way to do this?

How I envisage it working is something like:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "Zephyr|classpath:zephyr.properties")
public class RunCukeTestsIT {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar with HP ALM the other day. The best I could manage looked like this:

```
@CucumberOptions(features="target/")
public class CucumberRunner() {

  @BeforeClass
  public void getFeatures() {
    //get the files from server
    //save them to /target/, mark them as temporary
  }
}
```

If there's a more elegant option than this then I too would be interested to know. One particular problem is that it doesn't work with tags; if you specify tags to run in @CucumberOptions, it will search for them before downloading the features and then report them as not present.

Comment: Thanks... might use this as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

if you run as java project you can achieve this. your code will first download the scenarios from ALM/JIRA and store in resources folder, so the next step would be to run the Junit test class with cucumber options pointing to that feature file.